# Scala gradle console app with java libararies

Tags: scala, gradle

I have Scala console app that uses a java library. I am new to both Gradle and Scala. I am not using any IDE, just VS Code and Gradle.
I can build the app using Gradle, but when trying to run I get an exception, class not found.

```
$ gradle run
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class
        at scopt.Head$.<init>(options.scala:148)
        at scopt.Head$.<clinit>(options.scala)
        at scopt.OptionParser.head(options.scala:251)
        at console.App$$anon$1.<init>(App.scala:20)
        at console.App$.main(App.scala:19)
        at console.App.main(App.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Product$class
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 6 more
```

I am guessing that jar files are not getting copied into the build/distribution or build/libs folder.

The build file looks like:

```
    plugins {
    // Apply the scala plugin to add support for Scala
    id 'scala'
    id 'application'
    id 'distribution'
}

repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
    maven {
            url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.7'
    implementation 'org.mongodb.scala:mongo-scala-bson_2.12:2.5.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:4.0.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.11.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.11.1'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:1.7.25'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.0.1'
    implementation group: 'com.github.scopt', name: 'scopt_2.11', version: '3.7.1'
    implementation group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '27.0.1-jre'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api-scala_2.12', version: '11.0'
    implementation 'com.github.pcj:google-options:1.0.0'

    // Use Scalatest for testing our library
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.scalatest:scalatest_2.12:3.0.5'

    // Need scala-xml at test runtime
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:1.1.1'
}
group = 'matches'
version = '1.0'
description = 'matches'
sourceCompatibility = '11'
mainClassName = 'console.App'

application {
    mainClassName = "console.App"
}
```

I am not sure what I need to add to the build.

Comment: I recommend defining and using a custom function to specify Scala dependencies, because otherwise you're forced to specify the Scala major version in every dependency. Try something like https://github.com/yawaramin/newtype/blob/23660ac0811225c2870b3a5c622c949b9262788f/build.gradle , then you can do `implementation scala('com.github.scopt', 'scopt', '3.7.1')`

Comment: Good idea @Yawar - thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing libraries os scala 2.11 and scala 2.12. Change scopt to
implementation group: 'com.github.scopt', name: 'scopt_2.12', version: '3.7.1'